# Uniform continuity of functions on open interval

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Which  of the following functions/is uniformly continuous on the interval (0,1)?

1. $$J(x)=\frac{1}{x}$$
2. $$J(x) = x \sin \frac{1}{x}$$
3. $$J(x) = \sin \frac{1}{x}$$
4. $$J(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$$

I think second and fourth option are correct, since interval is open, and both functions converges to $0$ as $x$ approaches infinity. Am I right?

Comment: You are interested in the behavior as $x$ approaches $0$ from the right. The behavior as $x$ approaches infinity is not relevant (the second function does not approach $0$ as $x$ tends to infinity, incidentally).

Comment: I've typeset your equations, please make sure that I interpreted them properly.

Comment: A function is uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$ if and only if it can be extended continuously to $[0,1]$. So you jsut need to check whether finite limits exist at $0^+$ and $1^-$.

Comment: You are correct, but they are not uniformly continuous because the interval is open. As David mentioned, the behaviour at infinity is of no relevance here.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to formalize this idea of "convergent at the boundaries $\Rightarrow$ uniformly continuous".

For the second function : $\lim_{x \to 0} J(x) = 0$.

Let $J' : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R} ; x \mapsto \begin{cases} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} &&\text{if }x>0 \\ 0 &&\text{if } x=0 \end{cases}$.

This function is continous on a closed interval of $\mathbb{R}$. Thus it is uniformly continous (Heine Theorem). So $J$, which is its restriction to $(0,1]$, is uniformly continuous.